# Proof of conditions for a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

In Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right" a subspace is defined as follows:

> A subset $U$ of $V$ is a called a subspace of $V$ if $U$ is also a vector space (using the same addition and scalar multiplication as on $V$

It is also stated that

> A subset $U$ of $V$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $U$ satisfies the following three conditions:
> **additive identity:** $0 \in U$
> **closed under addition:** $u,w \in U$ implies $u + w \in U$
> **closed under scalar multiplication:** $a \in \bf{F}$ and $u \in U$ implies $au \in U$

The proof in the text is very brief, so I just want to make sure I understand this statement by giving my own.

Proof: Let $V$ be an arbitrary vector space. Let $U$ be a subset of $V$.

$(\rightarrow)$ Suppose that $U$ is a subspace of $V$. This means that $U$ is a vector space. By definition, we know that there is some additive identity $ 0 \in U$. Now let $u,w \in U$ be arbitrary. Since $U$ is closed under addition, $u+w \in U$. Let $a \in \bf{F}$ and $u \in U$ be arbitrary. Since $U$ is closed under scalar multiplication, $au \in U$.

$(\leftarrow)$ Now suppose that $U$ has an additive identity and is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Commutativity: Let $u, w \in U$ be arbitrary. It follows that $u + w \in U$. But since $U \subseteq V$, $u + w \in V$. Then since $V$ is a vector space and has the commutative property, it follows that $u+w = w+ u$.

Associativity (scalar): Let $a,b \in \bf{F}$ and $u \in U$ be arbitrary. Clearly, $ab \in \bf{F}$. So then $(ab)u \in U$. Since $U \subseteq V$, $(ab)u \in V$. But since $V$ is a vector space, $(ab)u = a(bu)$.

Associativity (vector): Let $u,v, w \in U$ be arbitrary. Then since $u+v \in U$, $(u + v) + w \in U$. So $(u + v) + w \in V$. Since $V$ is a vector space, $(u + v) + w = u + (v+ w)$.

Additive Identity: It was assumed that $U$ has an additive identity.

Additive Inverse: Let $u \in U$ be arbitrary. Let $w = -1 u \in U$. We then have

\begin{align}
u + w &= u + (-1 u) \\
&= 1u + (-1  u) \\
&= (1 + (-1)) u \\
&= (0) u \\
&= 0
\end{align}

Multiplicative Identity: Let $u \in U$ be arbitrary. Then since $1 \in \bf{F}$, $1u \in U$. So $1u \in V$. Since $1v = v$ for all $v \in V$, $1u = u$.

Distributive properties: Let $a \in \bf{F}$ and $u, w \in U$ be arbitrary. Then $u + w \in U$ and $a(u + w) \in U$. Since $U \subseteq V$, $a(u + w) \in V$. Then since $V$ has the distributive property, $a(u + w) = au + aw$. Now let $a,b \in \bf{F}$ and $u \in U$ be arbitrary. Since $a +b \in \bf{F}$ and $u \in U$, $(a +b)u \in U$. Then since $U \subseteq V$, $(a+b)u \in V$. Since $V$ has the distributive property, $(a+b)u = au + bu$.

$\square$

Comment: Your proof is correct.